# Error when running .net 8 application with XM Cloud in local docker containers (XM Cloud Introduction) - Error NETSDK1045

Tags: docker, xm-cloud, .net

I wanted to run the [XM Cloud Introduction](https://github.com/Sitecore/XM-Cloud-Introduction) Repo in local docker containers.

Reproduction steps:

1. I cloned the main branch to my local
2. I ran the init script
3. I adjusted the `.env` file as I'm running on windows 10
4. I stopped IIS
5. I made sure docker is running for windows and not for Linux
6. I installed dotnet 8 to meet the head application requirements
7. I ran the up script

The following error occurs on step 15/20:

[image]

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Project\MvpSite\rendering\Mvp.Project.MvpSite.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\Navigation\rendering\Mvp.Feature.Navigation.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\BasicContent\rendering\MVP.Feature.BasicContent.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\Social\rendering\Mvp.Feature.Social.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Foundation\Configuration\rendering\Mvp.Foundation.Configuration.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\People\rendering\Mvp.Feature.People.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\User\rendering\Mvp.Feature.User.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Foundation\DataFetching\rendering\Mvp.Foundation.DataFetching.Rendering.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Feature\Selections\rendering\Mvp.Feature.Selections.Rendering.csproj]
```

Answer (score 4):

I first thought this might be related to an old windows version I was running on. So I updated it. But that did not help. So,inspecting the docker image using

```
docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

revealed that my docker image was from 2022 and not the one from 12th december 2023

Seems this package cannot handle the .net 8 but only .net 6

So I manually pulled latest

```
docker image pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

after inspecting that version it looked like I have the new version.

[image]

I ran the up.ps1 script again and the problem was solved.

Comment: This also helped me with a similar error for dotnet 7: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(151,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [C:\build\src\Project\MvpSite\rendering\Mvp.Project.MvpSite.Rendering.csproj]`